# sed -r (e.g echo "aa" | sed -r 's/o*/_/g')

Tags: bash, sed

I tried the command below on terminal
    `echo "aa" | sed -r 's/o*/_/g'`
The result was like this
    `_a_a_`
What I expected was
    `__`
When the first `a` is read, it means that there's zero `o` so that `a` would be replaced by `_`

If I use
`echo "aoooa" | sed -r 's/o+/_/g'`
The result is as what I expected
`a_a`

But when I use
`echo "aoooa" | sed -r /s/o*/_/g`
The result is
`_a_a_`
I think it should be `_a_a` and without the last `_`

I totally had no idea why there were 3 underscores. Could anyone tell me the running process of this specific case?

Comment: please edit you Q to show the output you **do** expect. AND recall that `*` means zero-or-more-of-the-preceding-text-object with the emphasis on zero-or-more. AND of course, why do you expect `s/o/g` to change `a` (or `l` as you have in your subject line)? Good luck.

Comment: When it reads the first `a`, I think the condition `o*` was satisfied because there's no `o` and `a` would be replaced by `_`

Comment: If you are trying to replace 'a' by '_' `sed 's/a/_/g'` should be enough.
If you want to replace any letter(a-z) then you can use `'s/[a-z]/_/g'`

Comment: So can you please explain this command for me  
`echo "aoooa" | sed 's/[o]*/_/g'`  
The result is
`_a_a_`  
Why are there 3 underscores?

Comment: You should enclose `*` inside quotes to prevent unexpected globing.
From your above command I assume that you're trying to replace all `o` with `_`. In that case using `*` is quite unnecessary. You can simply do this by `sed 's/o/_/g'`

Comment: @DuongHoang `o*` does not match the "a", it matches the zero-length string *before* the "a" (and the zero-length string between the "a"s, and the zero-length string after the second "a"). The "a" marks the end of the match, but it is not *part of* the match, and hence does not get replaced.

Comment: Many thanks! @GordonDavisson

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Right! I couldn't quite put that into words, Post as an answer and I'll upvote. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From my comment:] `o*` does not match the "a", it matches the zero-length string before the "a" (and the zero-length string between the "a"s, and the zero-length string after the second "a"). The "a" marks the end of the match, but it is not part of the match, and hence does not get replaced.

To make this clearer, consider what happens when there *are* runs of "o"s (and I used capital "A"s to make them more visible):

```
$ echo "ooooAooooAoooo" | sed 's/o*/_/g'
_A_A_
```

...each group of "o"s gets replaced by a single "_"; the "A"s end the first two groups, but they aren't part of the groups (they're between the groups), so they get left alone.

If there's just one "o" in a group, the same thing happens:

```
$ echo "oAoAo" | sed 's/o*/_/g'
_A_A_
```

...and finally, with no "o"s (i.e. with zero-length groups of "o"s):

```
$ echo "AA" | sed 's/o*/_/g'
_A_A_
```

...again, the "A"s aren't part of the matches, so they don't get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

If the output desired is anything starting with o, with underscore on letters that are not o, you could use:

```
 echo "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzoo" | sed -r 's/[^o]/_/g'
```

Output:  _____________o___________oo